# android device id confusion

Tags: java, android, device

If I dial 
<kbd>*</kbd> 
<kbd>#</kbd>
<kbd>*</kbd> 
<kbd>#</kbd>
<kbd>8</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>5</kbd>
<kbd>5</kbd>
<kbd>#</kbd>
<kbd>*</kbd> 
<kbd>#</kbd>
<kbd>*</kbd> 
, I get my android device id which starts with `android-`**`35c2acdd...`**

[image: source]  [source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1563894)

If I use `Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)` the result starts with **`a96b4b27...`**

If I use `((TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId()` the result starts with **`3538330...`**

What is the difference between these ID-s? How can I get the result of the

<kbd>*</kbd> 
<kbd>#</kbd>
<kbd>*</kbd> 
<kbd>#</kbd>
<kbd>8</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>5</kbd>
<kbd>5</kbd>
<kbd>#</kbd>
<kbd>*</kbd> 
<kbd>#</kbd>
<kbd>*</kbd> 
 dial?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**IMEI**

The IMEI is the '[MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_access_control)' for the telephony module - the unique ID that the telephone uses when it connects via GSM/GPRS/HSPDA/etc. The GSM network uses it to route calls and data from the phone over the GSM network right up to the gateway into the Internet (which is an IP network).

A telephony module is a chip or circuit board that handles the telephone network, either GSM or CMDA, and often has a slot for a removable SIM card. Some phones have more than one telephony module (active dual- or multi-SIM phones). Each telephony module has its own IMEI.

Manufacturers give each phone (strictly the telephony module) a unique IMEI during manufacturing. However the number can normally be rewritten if you have the right software. This is often done after a phone has been stolen to give the phone a new identity and bipass stolen phone blocking system.

The IMEI can be programmatically obtained using the [TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()) API.

**CDMA phones have a ESN or MEID** which are [different lengths and formats](http://infusio.wordpress.com/2007/06/22/what-are-esnimeimeid/), even though it is retrieved using the same API.

Android devices without telephony modules - for example many tablets and TV devices - *do not have an IMEI*. As [Schlangi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576300/schlangi) commented, some devices that do not have a telephony module *fake* the IMEI, so the presence of an IMEI does not (always) guarantee the device has a telephony module.

**ANDROID_ID**

The ANDROID_ID is another unique number on the phone - this is automatically generated by the OS as it boots for the first time (doing it this way makes it *much* easier for the manufacturers by removing a step from the production line).

The ANDROID_ID can (and does) change, for example:

- Factory reset (including when reflashing the OS)
- In software: eg https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vcastroi.changeid

It is mainly used by developers (eg identifying and connecting to devices using `adb`)

ANDROID_ID can be used to identify an Android device given the caveats above, realistically meaning that it uniquely identifies the device over significant portions of the device lifetime, but cannot be relied on.

Also note that there was a bug in Froyo where many devices gave themselves the *same* ANDROID_ID. This is the [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10603)

**Other identifiers**

There are a number of other things that can be used identify the device:

- MAC address of the WiFi module: [WifiManager.getConnectionInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConnectionInfo()) -> [WifiInfo.getMacAddress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getMacAddress()). This can often be changed in software, but *generally* is constant over the device lifetime. Also it can only be read if the WiFi module is switched on.
- MAC address of the BlueTooth module: [BluetoothAdaptor.getAddress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getAddress()). Like WiFi MAC, this can often be changed in software and may be off when you need it
- The subscriber's telephone number. This may change if the user requests a new number from the telco, or if the user switches SIMs. It is obtained from [TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number()). This is only present for Android phone devices with a current SIM installed and a paid service with a telco.
- The SIM contains its own identifying number ([IMSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Subscriber_Identity)). This is obtained from the [TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSubscriberId()) API. Obviously the SIM may not be present at any specific time, and it changes when the SIM is changed - and users can upgrade/replace their SIM while keeping the same number, so you can't say that this is one-to-one to a specific phone or user.
- Related to the IMSI is the [MSISDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN). This functions as the identification of a *subscription* (your contract for a specific telephone number with your mobile provider) and therefore gives the device its telephone number. The MSISDN may be associated with several SIM cards, and therefore several phones. It comes with all the caveats for reading the SIM above. This may be retrieved with [TelephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimSerialNumber()). Thanks [Schlangi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576300/schlangi) for the corrections and additions
- Gingerbread and later has [android.os.Build.SERIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL) which many manufacturers set (but not all. Bugger).

**Other notes**

You need specific permissions to access each and every API, so if you try for all of them, your app's permissions in the Google Play store look fairly permissive.

I think this link explains all the other available options also https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: Although you are right with your statement that devices without telephony module do not have an IMEI, there are manufacturers that give their devices fake-IMEIs. One example for that is a low cost device of Odys named Loox plus - so if you try to handle those devices in a special way, do not count on getting null or empty string when calling TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()!

Comment: I found one minor mistake in your explanation: the IMSI is reported by TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId(), the serial number of the SIM card is a different thing: It is possible to make multiple copies of a SIM card, all using the same IMSI but different serial numbers. The result are SIM cards, which can be used in different phones to have the same phone number (e.g. smartphone and car phone) but only one at a time. This was a common use case before the mobile network could handle multiple IMSIs per phone number that can be used simultaniously.

Comment: @Schlangi: Thanks for your comments - I've updated my answer to clarify all those details. Please let me know if I've munged things up :)

Comment: is it feasible for android 10 ?https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids

Answer (score 8):

Found on the web:

```
private static final Uri URI = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices");
private static final String ID_KEY = "android_id";

String getAndroidId(Context ctx) {
    String[] params = { ID_KEY };
    Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver()
            .query(URI, null, null, params, null);

    if (!c.moveToFirst() || c.getColumnCount() < 2)
        return null;

    try {
        return Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(c.getString(1)));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

However, I doubt that is a documented ID and I would be carefull because that might not work if GTalk gets updated.

Source: http://blog.codepainters.com/2012/01/17/how-to-obtain-gtalk-android-id/

Also worth having a look at: http://www.toxicbakery.com/android-development/getting-google-auth-sub-tokens-in-your-android-applications/

Comment: This an ID specific to Google services on the phone. It is generated when you set up the first (primary) Google account to the device. It's just long (64 bit) number, and is used in all Google services, including the Android Market. Unless you are trying to write an app that accesses Google Services you don't generally need it (Cf. the second link above).

Answer (score 5):

There are some approach  to get unique identifier on android phone.

1. Android ID
   It is a 64-bit hex string which is generated on the device's first boot.
   Generally it won't changed unless is factory reset.

   Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

The Android ID , considered unreliable because it can sometimes be null.
The documentation states that it "can change upon factory reset".
This string can also be altered on a rooted phone.

```
   String m_szAndroidID = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Returns: 9774d56d682e549c . No special permissions required.
```

2. The WLAN MAC Address string, is another unique identifier that you can use as a device id.
 Before you read it, you will need to make sure that your project has the android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
 permission or the WLAN MAC Address will come up as null.

```
 WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 String m_szWLANMAC = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
Returns: 00:11:22:33:44:55 (not a real address since this is a custom ROM , as you can see the MAC address can easily be faked).
WLAN doesn't have to be on, to read this value.
```

3. The BT MAC Address string, available on Android devices with Bluetooth, can be read if your project has the android.permission.BLUETOOTH permission.

```
    BluetoothAdapter m_BluetoothAdapter = null; // Local Bluetooth adapter
    m_BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
   String m_szBTMAC = m_BluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```

Returns: 43:25:78:50:93:38 . BT doesn't have to be on, to read it.
4. IMEI only for Android devices with Phone use:

```
 TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String szImei = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); // Requires READ_PHONE_STATE
```

This requires adding a permission in AndroidManifest.xml, and users will be notified upon installing
 your software: android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE. The IMEI is unique for your phone 
 and it looks like this: 359881030314356 (unless you have a pre-production device with an invalid IMEI like 0000000000000).
For more info [refer](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1662) this link.

Answer (score 3):

IMEI

*There is a mandatory requirement by the standardization bodies, that mobile devices for public networks may be uniquely identified by the IMEI number*

It is the manufacturer's responsibility to set IMEI. In practice, developers sometimes see IMEIs like 000000... or 123456... Sometimes phones with identical IMEI go to production, which of course is a bug that *should* be fixed...

ANDROID_ID

*A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated on the device's first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the device. (The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.)*

It looks like Android does not trust the manufacturers and provides an alternative unique ID.

EDIT:

This is what I get (instead of IMEI) on and Android device that is *not* a phone:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo
Phone Subscriber Info:
  Phone Type = GSM
  Device ID = null
```

Comment: how can i get the result of the `*#*#8255#*#*` dial?

Answer (score 1):

I think all the information provided above is well enough to understand the codes.

Yet I think you are still "not able to see the result of the *#*#8255#*#* dial" (plz excuse if I went wrong somewhere in understanding this)

I assume the reason behind this is one of the latest bug fix against USSD code made in Android.
(you may read more about this and check if your device is on the list. its all over the web)

Finally, if you just want to get the android ID straightaway i suggest you to use this app-

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redphx.deviceid&hl=en