# How can I get the android device id which I get on dialing " *#*#8255#*#* "

Tags: java, android

How can I get the android device id which I get on dialing
<kbd>*</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>

I am using the following code but it does not return the same...what I want

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(getActivity()
                .getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting question and has been discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744565/android-device-id-confusion

Comment: Sorry but that link was not exactly the thing I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the code you tried probably returns a dynamic ID. Try this.

private static final Uri URI = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices");
       private static final String ID_KEY = "android_id";

```
   String getAndroidId(Context ctx) {
       String[] params = { ID_KEY };
       Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver()
               .query(URI, null, null, params, null);
       try{

       if (!c.moveToFirst() || c.getColumnCount() < 2){
           return null;
       }
       }catch(Exception e){
           return null;
       }

       try {
           Toast.makeText(ctx, Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(c.getString(1))), 500).show();
           System.out.println("android id  " + Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(c.getString(1))));

           return Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(c.getString(1)));

       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           return null;
       }
   }
```

In the above code Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(c.getString(1))), returns the android device id.

Comment: Do we need some permissions also.... because it is giving some runtime exception.

Comment: I have used following permission and it's working fine...Thanks a lot...<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES">
</uses-permission>

Comment: yes..You need to add permissions...sorry about that....glad it worked:)