# How to get location of android device by its android id

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2, gprs

I  am new in android and recently start learning about Android and I am trying to get location of any android device by its unique android id. By that I can track the approx or exact location either by GPS or network provider. In detail I mean to say that whenever i enter any Android id in my app i can get device location in my application. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Please read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744565/android-device-id-confusion/13831099#13831099 And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: Is it possible to get location of any device who has my app in their mobile?

Comment: you can use analytics library in your application and send location data to analytics lib so you can finding location of devices in which your app is running

Comment: can you share any example code to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I am able to do with this code:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener{
String GPS_FILTER = "";
Thread triggerService;
LocationListener locationListener;
LocationManager lm;
private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meter

private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 3; // 1 minute
protected LocationManager locationManager;
boolean isRunning = true;

Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Location location;
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude;
UserFunctions userFunction;
private JSONObject json;
private AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_FLAG = "flag";
String android_id ;
String userName;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
            0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    if (getAccount() != null) {
        userName = getAccount();
    }

    GPS_FILTER = "MyGPSLocation";
    // locationManager = (LocationManager)
    // getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    // LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
    // MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
    // MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
    // new MyLocationListener());
    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            60 * 1000*3, pintent);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    //turnGPSOn();
    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();*/
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
     locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, (LocationListener) this);
     if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latitude + ", ll" + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();*/
                userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                new YourAsyncTaskLogin().execute();
            }
        }

     location =locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 1.0f, locationListener);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    // removeGpsListener();
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

// private void removeGpsListener(){
// try{
// lm.removeUpdates(locationManager);
// }
// catch(Exception ex){
// System.out.println("Exception in GPSService --- "+ex);
// }
// }

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        postdata(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
        /*Toast.makeText(MyService.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        turnGPSOff();*/
    }

    private void postdata(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                latitude + ", " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        // Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Provider status changed",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        // Toast.makeText(MyService.this,
        // "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        // Toast.makeText(MyService.this,
        // "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

public void turnGPSOn() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        this.sendBroadcast(poke);

    }
}

// automatic turn off the gps
public void turnGPSOff() {
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        this.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


class YourAsyncTaskLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    //private ProgressDialog _ProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // show your dialog here

        /*_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "",
                "Loading", true);*/

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        json = userFunction.sendLocations(android_id, userName,latitude+"", longitude+"");
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
            Log.e("Key_Success:",
                    json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS));
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                // loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {



                } else {
                    // Error in login
                    // loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");

                    //_ProgressDialog.cancel();


                }

            } else {
                // Error in login
                // loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");

                //_ProgressDialog.cancel();         

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }

        //_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
public String getAccount() {
    AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    Account[] list = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    if (list.length != 0) {
        String email = list[0].name;
        return email;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get location of any device who has your app in their mobile , you can get it ,
firstly in your app you can upload locations to your server with memberid(you can set it , unique for every device) for every x time(you can set it how many times you update the location).
And then you can check your db on your server which device in where.

(my advice you can use webservice to update db on your server)

Comment: how can i submit its location from device to server while app is not running?

Comment: You can write a service on android.

Comment: I got an idea from it and trying to do that by service but still not getting exact things that i want.

Comment: still i am not able to do that can you please give me an example code to do so?

Comment: how can I do that , it is a project , I cant time to write project , but the way is simple it should be server side project

Comment: ok but can u provide me a code snippet or any link from where i can do that because i did't find any relevant method to do so

Comment: I can't rate up this answer as i need 15 minimum reputation to rate this answer up..

Comment: Ok now i did that can you please now help me out to get my problem resolved ?

Comment: let me search time to find project but I dont think so , you can write a webservice and on android client you can get location and post server via webservice , and then you can know which user is where , is it right?

Comment: yes we can but as i am new into android so can't find relevant solution or method to do so.. that's why i am pushing you to please assist me and solve my issue.