# Is it possible to track GPS location in android even if user didn't open the app

Tags: android, mobile, gps, geolocation

I have a requirement where we need to get users location whether or not he opened the app. Is there any possible way we can do it in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible by using `Services` and `AlarmManager` classes to trigger application in background.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727409/3360307)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use alarm manager. Use the new location services API (available all the way back to API 8) and request location updates. See [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) for explanation and example.